# diskutil eraseDisk results in Error: 12: POSIX reports: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: usb, disk-utility, error

I'm trying to format my usb drive that is partitioned with FAT32 by the following command in Terminal:

```
$ diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ UntitledUFS disk1
```

However, I get this output:

```
Started erase on disk1
Unmounting disk
Error: 12: POSIX reports: Cannot allocate memory
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be likely that you are not running the command as admin (Unix root) user.

To run a command with administrator privileges use the sudo command so:

```
$ sudo diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ UntitledUFS disk1
```

The error message can lead one astray giving the impression that something else is wrong but it is likely a permissions issue.